# Get unix timestamp value from only year in android

Tags: java, android, unix

How to get Unix timestamp value only for particular year.

I have a situation where in server side for DOB i store only year. So in android i take Age value and then subtract current year with the age and send that year to server. To send that year i need to convert to Unix timestamp because in server side it stores in Unix timestamp format.

Somebody please help what can be done. I saw some links which uses `getTime()` and divide it by 1000. But that would be whole year with date and month.

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "subtract current year with the age" - and which of the huge number of Unix timestamps you want for the year. Would midnight on January 1st, UTC, be appropriate?

Comment: You should definitely learn the difference between a timestamp and a year - a timestamp describes a certain point in time, to the millisecond.

Comment: I get current year and i am converting it to integer and then age which user enters. For example, current year is 2014 and he puts age as 20 so his dob year is 1994. I wanted timestamp value of 1994. And i wanted in GMT.

Comment: 1994 is a year and no timestamp - when you want to process the year where one was birthed, use an integer and no timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, theYear); // Set the year you want
myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
myCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
myCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
Date theDate = myCal.getTime();
```

Comment: Adboco thDate will have value 31 dec even though you set month and day to 0.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

> I get current year and i am converting it to integer and then age which user enters. For example, current year is 2014 and he puts age as 20 so his dob year is 1994. I wanted timestamp value of 1994. And i wanted in GMT.

Apparently you want to the moments at each end of a year.

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old legacy date-time classes.

## Parse integer from string

First the year.

```
String input = "20" ;
integer age = Integer.parseInt( input ) ;
```

## Time zone

Determining a date, and therefore a year, requires a time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone][2] explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## `Year`

Get the current year.

```
Year currentYear = Year.now( z ) ;
```

## `LocalDate` & `ZonedDateTime`

Get the first day of the year as a `LocalDate`. From that, get the first moment of the day as a `ZonedDateTime`. A day does not always start at 00:00, so let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
LocalDate firstOfYear = currentYear.atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime yearStart = firstOfYear.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Half-Open

Use Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time, where beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
LocalDate firstOfFollowingYear = currentYear.plusYears( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime yearStop = firstOfFollowingYear.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Count-from-epoch

You do not specify what you mean exactly by “Unix timestamp”. I will guess you mean a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long start = yearStart.toEpochSecond() ;
long stop = yearStop.toEpochSecond() ;
```

For more discussion, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53464483/642706) to a similar Question.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).