# How to gain month and year only from unix timestamp

Tags: java

I have many timestamps in the format '1231469665', part of a dataset, and the task I'm doing needs me to find how many instances of an event happened each month in a dataset.

```
{
  int timestamp = 1231469665;
  java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long)timestamp*1000);
}
```

The above gives 'Fri Jan 09 02:54:25 UTC 2009' and I need to know only month and year of this.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Don't use java.util.Date. Use java.time.Instant. Convert it to a ZonedDateTime after choosing your timezone. Then ask the month to the ZonedDateTime. The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: what timezone do you convert them into is the question here

Comment: unix timestamps are just all seconds counted since 1.1.1970, do the math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Parse count-from-epoch

Assuming your input `1231469665` is an integer number representing the number of whole seconds since the Unix Time [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then parse as a `Instant`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = 1_231_469_665L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( secondsSinceEpoch );
```

Generate text representing the value of that [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> 2009-01-09T02:54:25Z

## Determine month

Next we need to determine the month of that moment. The trick there is that determining dates, and therefore determining a month, **depends on a time zone**. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal). By the same logic, if on the last day of the month, it could be “next month” in Paris while still “last month” in Montréal.

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Define your time zone, and apply it to the `Instant` to view that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of that particular region.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2009-01-09T15:54:25+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

Now get the month as a whole, a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from( zdt ) ;
```

## Half-Open

Generally best in date-time handling to define a span-of-time using the Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a month starts with the first moment of the first of the month and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the first of the *following* month.

So we need to get the first of the month. From that get the first moment of the day. Let *java.time* determine that moment, as a day does *not* always start at 00:00:00.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = yearMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = firstOfMonth.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Add a month, and do the same.

```
LocalDate firstOfFollowingMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = firstOfFollowingMonth.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Relational Database

I do not know what you mean by “dataset”. If you meant a relational database, use JDBC 4.2 or later to directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

The JDBC spec requires support for `OffsetDateTime` but not `ZonedDateTime`. You would try `ZonedDateTime` with your particular driver. If not supported, convert to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime start = zdtStart.toOffsetDateTime() ;
OffsetDateTime stop = zdtStop.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Write your SQL using `>= AND <` logic. Do *not* use the `BETWEEN` command.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE when >= ? AND when < ? ;
```

Use `setObject` in your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
```

For retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Tracking count-from-epoch

If your mysterious dataset operates on the count of whole seconds, you can ask the start and stop `ZonedDateTime` objects for such a count.

```
long start = zdtStart.toEpochSecond() ;
long stop = zdtStop.toEpochSecond() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

The Java time api makes this easy. Use `Instant.ofEpochSecond(long)` to get an `Instant`, and then `LocalDateTime.ofInstant()` to get a `LocalDateTime`. Finally, that will give you year and month like

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.printf("year = %d, month = %s%n", ldt.getYear(), ldt.getMonth());
```

I get (for 1231469665)

```
year = 2009, month = JANUARY
```

Comment: If thinking of using it in Android, this java.time.Instant#ofEpochSecond requires API level 26 and higher.

Answer (score -1):

You're not clear if you need to FORMAT how the date is displayed, or if you want to EXTRACT the month and year.

- Format: Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (any version of Java)
- Get month and/or year: [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):, [java.time.YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), etc. (only Java8 or higher)

Comment: Please, don't advise using SimpleDateFormat and Date. They're obsolete. java.time has all you need to format, too.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I'm still writing software for a number of enterprises (large companies - names you'd recognize) that haven't UPGRADED to Java 1.7 from Java 1.6 yet.  And just because something is "old" doesn't mean it's bad.  Nor does "new" necessarily mean "good".  PS: Nowhere in the Javadoc for [java.Text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) does it say "deprecated".  Personally, I prefer it :)